# aws rds postgres9.6: after db restore geo location column returns string instead of object

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds, postgis

I have an automated restore script which has been running for about 1y, but within the last month'ish something has changes which is causing the geo request to come back as a string instead of an object. Older databases in the same cluster return correctly with exactly the same value, so i am struggling to work out whats wrong with the column/data after I have done a restore??

I have a test nodejs script, which is using sequelize as the ORM to test agains the dbs in isolation. I originally thought it was an issue with the ORM but considering it works on one db and not the other, with exactly the same data, makes me think there is something wrong with the restored database. The code block that returns as string and not object is :

```
geoPointLocation: {
    type: Sequelize.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
    defaultValue: DEFAULT_GEOPOINT,
},
...
const geoPointLocation = this.getDataValue('geoPointLocation');
...
```

From the database it "looks" like they are exactly the same but obviously i am missing something?

query executed by the framework :

```
SELECT "name", "address", "geoPointLocation" FROM "Locations" AS "Locations" WHERE "Locations"."name" = 'this-issue-sucks';
```

Working database <<

```
postgres@working_db=> select ST_IsValid("geoPointLocation") from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-
st_isvalid | t

postgres@working_db=> select st_asText("geoPointLocation") from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------
st_astext | POINT(-77.0365739 38.8976633)

postgres@working_db=> select "geoPointLocation" from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-------------------------------------------
geoPointLocation | 0101000000C7180E3A574253C0E3288AA1E6724340
```

Failing database <<

```
postgres@temp_geo=> select ST_IsValid("geoPointLocation") from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-
st_isvalid | t

postgres@temp_geo=> select st_asText("geoPointLocation") from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------
st_astext | POINT(-77.0365739 38.8976633)

postgres@temp_geo=> select "geoPointLocation" from "Locations" where name = 'this-issue-sucks';
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+---------------------------------------------------
geoPointLocation | 0101000020E6100000C7180E3A574253C0E3288AA1E6724340
```